# How to save card after payment in stripe?

Tags: asp.net-core, stripe-payments

I want to save a card for next payments in my app, but always get the same exception : **"Stripe.StripeException: 'The provided PaymentMethod was previously used with a PaymentIntent without Customer attachment, shared with a connected account without Customer attachment, or was detached from a Customer. It may not be used again. To use a PaymentMethod multiple times, you must attach it to a Customer first.'
"**
I don't have any clue, how to solve it.

*Here is my Controller.cs:*

```
public class PaymentController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Processing()
        {
            var service = new PaymentMethodService();
            var obj=service.Get("pm_1ICLE7GcqJgpxMZpnTbfS7Jw");


            var paymentIntents = new PaymentIntentService();
            var paymentIntent = paymentIntents.Create(new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
            {
                Amount = 2000,
                Currency = "usd",
                Customer = "cus_Ing6wBxNYVdB44",
                ReceiptEmail = "eman29@jdecorz.com",
                PaymentMethod = obj.Id,
                Confirm = true,
                OffSession = true
            });//here exception is thrown


            return Json(new { clientSecret = paymentIntent.ClientSecret });
        }
    }
```

*My client.js code:*

```
var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51IBEAOGcqJgpxMZpvVKN2j9K7RJpzazfnG4u0relgSXiVBtNDd7nGgxBmX8BNCvuNerv1jnf0UVL5Uz8ODeJ7wvI00ruu2ByVM");

// Disable the button until we have Stripe set up on the page
document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
fetch("/Payment/Processing", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
})
    .then(function (result) {
        return result.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        var elements = stripe.elements();
        var style = {
            base: {
                color: "#32325d",
                fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
                fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
                fontSize: "16px",
                "::placeholder": {
                    color: "#32325d"
                }
            },
            invalid: {
                fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
                color: "#fa755a",
                iconColor: "#fa755a"
            }
        };
        var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
        // Stripe injects an iframe into the DOM
        card.mount("#card-element");
        card.on("change", function (event) {
            // Disable the Pay button if there are no card details in the Element
            document.querySelector("button").disabled = event.empty;
            document.querySelector("#card-error").textContent = event.error ? event.error.message : "";
        });
        var form = document.getElementById("payment-form");
        form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // Complete payment when the submit button is clicked
            payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);
        });
    });
// Calls stripe.confirmCardPayment
// If the card requires authentication Stripe shows a pop-up modal to
// prompt the user to enter authentication details without leaving your page.
var payWithCard = function (stripe, card, clientSecret) {
    loading(true);
    stripe
        .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: card
            }
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                // Show error to your customer
                showError(result.error.message);
            } else {
                // The payment succeeded!
                orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id);
            }
        });
};
/* ------- UI helpers ------- */
// Shows a success message when the payment is complete
var orderComplete = function (paymentIntentId) {
    loading(false);
    document
        .querySelector(".result-message a")
        .setAttribute(
            "href",
            "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments/" + paymentIntentId
        );
    document.querySelector(".result-message").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
};
// Show the customer the error from Stripe if their card fails to charge
var showError = function (errorMsgText) {
    loading(false);
    var errorMsg = document.querySelector("#card-error");
    errorMsg.textContent = errorMsgText;
    setTimeout(function () {
        errorMsg.textContent = "";
    }, 4000);
};
// Show a spinner on payment submission
var loading = function (isLoading) {
    if (isLoading) {
        // Disable the button and show a spinner
        document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
        document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
    } else {
        document.querySelector("button").disabled = false;
        document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
    }
};
```

I try to use samples from https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment and https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse, but can't understand, what I do wrongly

I know this is the dumb question, but it is my first expierence with Stripe and I can't to find any solution for this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When re-using a PaymentMethod for a Customer, it must be attached to them. There is a few ways to go about that. For example, one option is to create a payment method and then to call attach in the backend [1]. The other option is to collect card information using Stripe.js and Elements and to "setup future usage", this will automatically attach the card to the customer [2].

One thing to note, if your code uses `confirmCardPayment()` [3], that would normally be an "on-session" payment as the user is actively confirming the charge. [4]

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-data-setup_future_usage

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-off_session